# CSS pseudo after and before z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I have a strange issue with CSS pseudo after and before when I wanted to create a "ribbon"  - they just won't follow z-index for some reason !?

```
.posts-list .post .title {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background: #698800;
  z-index: 1;
}
.posts-list .post .title:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent #7d90a3 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px;
  height: 0;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.posts-list .post .title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7d90a3;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px;
  height: 0;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/182999yj/

Comment: remove the z-index on the main/real element. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/182999yj/1/)

Comment: This worked indeed, but WHY ? I mean - what's the problem in removing the parent z-index when I've placed the greater z-index on parent anyway ? Can you please explain me why is this working and with parent z-index doesn't ? Thanks !

Comment: The z-index property is quite difficult to understand. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) is a good article to start you off!